# Enable remote access neo4j 4.2 community edition

Tags: neo4j, remote-access

Due to working from home, I need a way to monitor a remote neo4j instance - preferably through a web browser instance.

In the past (eg in 3.0) it could be easily achieved by [modifying a single config line](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-enable-remote-https-access-with-neo4j-30x/).

Unfortunately, with the version 4.2 this is no more the case - the line is not there anymore and attempts to [coax the new connectors configs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/#connectors) to work in the same way, aka changing:

```
# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
#dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=false
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
#dbms.connector.https.advertised_address=:7473
```

to

```
# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474
#dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
dbms.connector.https.advertised_address=0.0.0.0:7473
```

did not succeed - the :7474 and :7473 remained inaccessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to uncomment the following configuration:

```
# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
#dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I must have not seen the line while scanning what was in the config files.

Comment: Working on enterprise edition as well. Thanks.